# How do I disable the Control+Shift+Down Arrow Hotkey?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I have a new Macbook Air with Lion and I'm using Excel in VMWare Fusion and it has a hotkey for <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>.

Every time I try and use this key combination instead of doing what it's supposed to do for Excel it's getting intercepted by Lion.

Is there a way to disable this hotkey globally or perhaps just when I'm using Fusion?

Comment: But what if I don't want to disable control-up and control-down for exposé, I only want to disable shift-control-up and shift-control-down for the silly "slow mo" exposé (to replace with Sublime Text 3's multiple-cursors)? thx! [Writing this comment on a previous answer as a "new answer", btw, b/c commenting requires more points than I currently have.]

Comment: My new question would be the same as this question, and I wouldn't want to duplicate. The answer marked correct above doesn't answer the original question exactly, it sidesteps it.

Comment: then lets tell that to @DanielLawson

Comment: You're absolutely right that my answer is a workaround. It's also the only way I know to solve the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove shift key augmentation for Mission Control animation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66433/remove-shift-key-augmentation-for-mission-control-animation)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To reassign the key globally, go to System Preferences » Mission Control and under Application Windows, where it currently says ^↓, assign another key (I used F10, à la exposé).

Comment: Thanks! This horrible shortcut was conflicting with sublimetext.

Comment: On Mavericks the key can be disabled completely, by assigning it a dash (latest option in the Mission Control and Application Windows dropdown box).

Answer (score 5):

To remove the shift augmentation follow the steps outlined in this answer to a similar (but with much less Google juice it seems) question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115698

Comment: This should be the accepted solution. The accepted solution does not disable Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down, rather it disables Mission Control which is the default target of Ctrl+Up/Down. This answer disables the shift augmentation which will free up Ctrl+Shift+Up/Down to be used by Sublime Text while keeping Ctrl+Up/Down intact for Mission Control.