# Remove shift key augmentation for Mission Control animation

Tags: macos, keyboard, mission-control

I recently upgraded to Mountain Lion and all of a sudden my key bindings for Sublime Text 2 multi-selection editing are no longer working. Specifically, I had key bindings set up for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up/Down arrow</kbd>.

Now Mission Control has taken over that key binding. How can I remove the Shift key augmentation (that causes the transition to be slower) for the shortcut?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can disable the keyboard shortcuts for slow-motion effects by following these instructions:

1. Open Terminal.
2. Open the `plist` file in your user's library preferences folder that contains the setting by typing `open ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` and hit <kbd>return</kbd>.
3. A window similar to this will open in Xcode:

[image: XCode PList Editor]

5. For items `34`, `35`, and `37`, set `enabled` to `NO`.
6. Close the file, click `Save` if prompted, and restart your system.
7. Enjoy.

Note: `34` and `35` may not be present in the plist if you have never opened the Mission Control preferences pane and changed the "Mission Control" or "Application windows" settings. If `37` isn't present either, simply add it yourself.

This process has been tested with:

- OS X Yosemite
- OS X El Capitan
- macOS Sierra

### Source

1. [MacWorld](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=114785)
2. [In Translation](http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2013/06/04/how-to-disable-the-shift-f10-slow-motion-animation-on-os-x-and-reclaim-the-keyboard-shortcut/)

Comment: Odd. I only have 18 entries in that and keys 34, 35 and 37 are not among them.

Comment: Awesome! Works on Yosemite too :)

Comment: I had to be explicit about opening in xcode: `open -a "Xcode" ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist`

Comment: Just logging off works too (no need to do full reboot if you don't want to)

Answer (score 7):

You can disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> shortcuts for Mission Control in the Keyboard preference pane. Just untick both "Mission Control" and "Application windows". This will also prevent the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd> key bindings, where the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key acts as a modifier to slow down the animation, as you have noticed.

[image: screenshot of Keyboard settings]

Disabling these shortcuts will allow you to use it again in Sublime Text 2 or other applications.

Comment: Yeah but I actually like having the Ctrl + Up/Down arrow shortcuts.  I JUST want to disable the Shift key portion of the key combination.

Comment: @LesterPeabody I'm afraid you cannot only disable the shift portion of these keybindings.

Comment: I see.  Well, that's just totally awesome.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The accepted answer doesn't work if you don't have Xcode installed.

Answer (score 4):

I am using Mavericks and opened the file in TextWrangler. Do not be shocked, it's in XML format.

Find the items 34,35 and 37 (check out [Behrang's post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115698/494)) and change the appropriate tag to `false` (this is the same as changing `enabled` to `NO` ). 
Like so

```
<key>37</key>
    <dict>
        <key>enabled</key>
        <false/>
```

Now you can happily use the key combination *with* <kbd>Shift</kbd> and rearrange your bullets and paragraphs without starting the slow expose animation.

Comment: Thanks very much. I didn't want to install xCode just to edit a single plist.