# Disable shift key slow animations from command line

Tags: macos, command-line, mission-control

The sole answer for [Remove shift key augmentation for Mission Control animation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66433/remove-shift-key-augmentation-for-mission-control-animation?noredirect=1&lq=1) that works is a GUI-based answer. I like to store all of my mac configuration in a version-controlled [dotfiles repository](https://github.com/codekiln/dotfiles) so I can quickly get back to ground zero when I make a new mac.

How can you disable the shift key slowness that occurs when you do Ctrl+Shift+Up Arrow and Ctrl+Shift+Down Arrow **from the command line**?

I've tried `defaults write com.apple.finder FXEnableSlowAnimation -boolean false; killall Finder`, which I found at [How to disable slow motion effect in Mac OS X (shift key)?](https://superuser.com/questions/121472/how-to-disable-slow-motion-effect-in-mac-os-x-shift-key). This does not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll have to log out and back in for this to work.